# Local time for specific time zone in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am in the process of porting an existing application to run on Windows Azure.  Our current solution relies heavily on the time zone Windows is set to on the SQL Server.  We use `GETDATE()` in our stored procedures and views quite frequently.  The problem is that SQL Azure running using the UTC time zone.  I'm trying to replace the `GETDATE()` method call with a method call that will get the time based on a setting in the database of what the time zone should be.  The problem I'm having is Daylight Saving Time.  Has anyone ever written a method in SQL that can return the current Date/Time and properly adjusting for DST?

I'm guessing that I'm going to get a few answers that will say that I should be using UTC times across the board.  That does not appear to be an option for reasons I'd rather not explain.

Any help/suggestions you can give me would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Hah you're right you should use UTC.  Converting to DST is a pain in the rear, and remember the rules changed a few years back as to when DST goes in and out of effect.  You could write a udf to do the conversion but it will be an expensive operation.

Comment: DST is quite a pain. In a previous life, I used a calendar table, since users had different time zone preferences, and different time zones may or may not be affected by DST, and certainly follow different schedules. So a user specified their time zone as a preference, and when they scheduled an event for 6 months from now, we stored the UTC time based on a lookup in the calendar table - we match the date and timezone and therefore know how to offset.

Comment: It *would* be nice to hear your reasons for wanting to use local time. There *are* some I'm aware of, but they're relatively rare. Looking at related SO questions and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/03/18/using-time-zone-data-in-sql-server-2008.aspx I suspect you're not going to find this an easy task. Does it definitely need to be within T-SQL itself? You can't pass the value as a parameter to your stored procedure?

Comment: I agree with @JonSkeet, you should be using GETUTCDATE() and storing UTC time. If you need to present it as local time, that's something you do when you pull the data out, not when you store it. IMHO.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I'm not saying that UTC would *definitely* be the way to go here. I'm just saying I'd be interested in hearing the reasons. There definitely *are* times when local time is more appropriate - for example, consider "The first meeting is at April 20th 2012, 3.30pm in Europe/London, and it repeats every fortnight" - knowing the time zone is very important then, and it's the *local* time which is repeated. Storing the UTC value would be less appropriate there, IMO. But such situations are relatively rare.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I did the passing as a parameter to all of the stored procedures I could.  That did make it a lot easier since those calls were being done in C# and TimeZoneInfo is amazing. Now I am stuck on a View that we use in a lot of locations.

Comment: Is the view supposed to convert to the same time zone no matter what? Or does it depend on the user or some other piece of information?

Comment: The 2 second answer to why we want to continue with local time is that our application is very large, we don't have any automated testing, and we have a deadline that is coming up fast. Few on the engineering staff here disagree that UTC is the way to go, but we are kind of stuck in the reality of our existing app.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I'm now noticing that the GETDATE() call is mostly being used to compare with 2 columns that exist in a lot of our tables (EffectiveDate and WhenExpire). We want to get the records that are effective today and have not expired. These values are just dates.  We want them to be midnight in the time zone defined in the database. When it was running at our client's location, it was midnight in the time zone that Windows was running.  We might be able to convert these columns to DateTimeOffset and use GETUTCDATE().

Comment: @Bryan: Just something to bear in mind - midnight doesn't always happen in all time zones. Probably not a problem if you're in the US, but in Brazil (for example) when the clocks go forward, they skip from 11:59:59pm to 1am the next day...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I am aware of that, but we only have clients in the US and Canada. We can safely make the assumption that that time will exist. We have a lot of other concerns if were to move into those areas.  But thanks.  On a side note Jon, I loved C# in Depth. Great read. Keep 'em coming.

Comment: I think that where this is most notable for my scenario is when we have data in SQL that is auto populated with getdate() and then the asp.net app needs to compare and look at dates.  If the server are out of synch then that messes up all sorts of data.  I also what the times to reflect our company's local time zone, not someone else’s. If we scale up to multiple zones then perhaps UTC might be the way to go but it seems a bit silly in such a small app to worry about that.  I’d love to be able to specify a local time zone for my db if it were possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have decided to update the columns in question to be `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`.

Thanks to all those who responded.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help you. But this executes a registry read on the SERVER registry. In the local context you can determine the difference between the SERVERs timezone and GMT and perofrm the necessary calcs you need from there. A usefull little trick I picked up from one of the other forums posts (Credit lies there).

```
Use Master
Go



DECLARE @ZONEDIFF INT

EXECUTE dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation','ActiveTimeBias', @ZONEDIFF OUT

SELECT getdate() AS MyTime, dateadd(minute, @ZONEDIFF, getdate() ) as SERVERZONE
```

Let me know if it helps or if I am not understanding you correctly.

Mac

Comment: If you only care about the current time zone difference, why not just `SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE());`, instead of bothering with XPs and the registry? I suspect the problem is more complicated than that though - and that you need to know the delta on a specific date, not just right now.

Comment: Sorry, that isn't exactly what I'm looking for.  I am more interested in the time zone that is set in our database (in a client's table).